# Is there a way to configure 'git commit -a' to NOT include submodule changes

Tags: git, git-submodules

The most common way to accidentally pick up submodule changes is to do a pull, forget to submodule update, and then do a `git commit -a` (which will add the submodule changes). Is there a way to configure Git so that it ignore submodule changes unless I specifically request it? Is there some other way to molly guard the situation?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I would question why you're so eager to use `git commit -a` ... I would definitely hand pick your changes to stage, then check your staged files before committing.

Comment: For complicated changes I make use of the index, but if I just pulled updates and edited a single file, `-a` saves me a little time and has very few ways to go wrong... unless there was a submodule update. I'm not alone in this...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an alias? Something as simple as `alias gca="git submodule update; git commit -a"` would work.

Alternatively, you can look into the wonderful world of [Git Hooks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks).

Neither of these solutions are typically shareable, however. For a shareable solution, you will need to look into a solution like [husky](https://npmjs.org/packages/husky) from the Node.js world.